# Creating a list with sequential numbers fast

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from time import time

mylist1 = []
mylist2 = []

start1 = time()
for i in range(100000000):
    mylist1.append(i)
end1 = time()

start2 = time()
mylist2 = [0] * 100000000
end2 = time()

print(end1-start1, end2-start2)
```

When I timed both actions to fill the list, I get 14 seconds for using for loop and 0.5 seconds for `mylist2 = [0] * 100000000`

So it seems it is obvious to use the second method if I need to insert massive amount of items at once.

But if I do the second thing, I have to insert the same number for all, or manually type  numbers that will repeat.

Is there a way to perform

```
for i in range(100000000):
    mylist1.append(i)
```

this action resulting in [0,1,2,3,...,n] with good speed?

The code doesn't necessarily have to be short if the speed is fast.

Comment: Why not use just `list(range(100000000))`, or better yet `np.arange(100000000)`?

Comment: What are you even doing with a list of a hundred million sequential integers, anyway? A list may not be the right data structure for the job - for example, `range(10**8)` may already be enough.

Comment: If you make a list from an object with a `len`, Python can use that value to guess at the size of the list it will end up making, so it doesn't have to constantly resize the list, which is expensive.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: `range` has a `len`, so `list(range(N))` (and `[*range(N)]` on Python 3.5+) will take advantage of that optimization already. That said, resizing the `list` isn't *that* expensive; since Python `list`s are just arrays of pointers, the worst case cost of each resize is just the worst case of `realloc`: Allocating new space, `memcpy`, free old space. The bigger cost here is repeatedly binding and calling `append`; there is non-trivial overhead to creating a bound method object (though 3.7 should reduce the need for it) and general function dispatch.

Comment: For example, using `ipython`'s `%%timeit` for microbenchmarking, the OP's code that repeatedly binds `append` takes about 9.3 seconds on my Linux 64 bit install of Python 3.6. If I tweak it to add `appendmylist1 = mylist1.append` outside the loop, and make the call in the loop `appendmylist1(i)`, that, by itself, reduces the cost of the whole loop to 6.19 seconds. A solid third of the total time (and about half the overhead above to `list(range(100000000))`) was just repeatedly performing the `LOAD_ATTR` involved in `mylist1.append`. Much of the rest is likely overhead of *calling* `append`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For full portability, `list(range(N))` will get the best performance [as Prune notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434858/364696). That said, if you're purely targeting Python 3.5 or higher, you can use [PEP 448's additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) to speed it up a small amount, with:

```
[*range(N)]
```

Note that this is a fixed savings, not per-item; all it does is bypass the lookup of `list` in the built-in namespace, and the generalized function call dispatch and `__init__` argument processing of the normal `list` constructor. So when you're talking about 100 million items, the savings are going to be lost in the noise; all this does is reduce the fixed overhead by (on my 3.6 install) 170±10 ns (e.g. `list(range(0))` takes 417 ns per call, vs. 247 ns per call for `[*range(0)]`).

In specific cases though, there is an even faster option:

```
mynotlist = range(100000000)
```

In modern Python, [`range` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) are [full fledged sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), they're just not mutable. So you can construct them, index them, slice them, compute their length, iterate them forwards and backwards, check membership (in `O(1)` for `int`s, unlike `list` where membership testing is `O(n)`), etc. The only non-mutability related features they lack are concatenation and repetition (with `+` and `*`), though you can simulate that with [`itertools` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) like [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (for concatenation), and [`islice`ing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) a [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) (for repetition).

**If you don't need to mutate the sequence, just read from it, using the `range` "raw" is *by far* the best option**; `range`s are lazy, consuming no memory, while still producing their values extremely efficiently. That laziness can be important; `list(range(100000000))` will require (on 64 bit Python) 3.45 *giga*bytes of memory for the `list` itself plus all the `int`s it contains; `range(100000000)` requires 48 *bytes*. The trivial cost of generating the values on the fly is more than worth it, given the memory savings.

If you need mutability, you can still save a bit on memory. If `numpy` is an option, [sacul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434904/364696) has you covered; if not, [Python's array module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) will save you a little bit of time, and a *lot* of memory. Compared to:

```
 list(range(100000000))
```

the `array` alternative:

```
 array.array('I', range(100000000))
```

takes about 10% less time (microbenchmarks had `list` at 3.39 sec, vs. `array.array` at 3.07 sec), and consumes *far* less memory (under ~391 MB, vs. the ~3529 MB of the `list` of `int`s). The main cost of `array` is limited range of values (e.g. for `'I'`, four byte `unsigned int`s can only store values in `range(2**32)`; the maximum range for `q`/`Q` format codes, using twice the memory, would be `range(-2**63, 2**63)`/`range(2**64)`).

Answer (score 2):

Try making a list of the `range` output:

```
mylist3 = list(range(100000000))
```

I added this to your tests and got these times:

```
append: 18.42
all-0:   0.23
list:    2.63       <== The new one
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you need speed, I think that `np.arange` is the best way to go, it's even faster than creating the list of all `0`s. Here are the timings on my machine:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np

def m1(n=100000000):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(n):
        mylist.append(i)
    return mylist

def m2(n=100000000):
    return [0] * n

def m3(n=100000000):
    return list(range(n))

def m4(n=100000000):
    return np.arange(n)

>>> timeit.timeit(m1,number=1)
17.615584995000972
>>> timeit.timeit(m2,number=1)
0.7669911839911947
>>> timeit.timeit(m3,number=1)
9.909814337006537
>>> timeit.timeit(m4,number=1)
0.5374436590063851
```

Note that `np.arange()` returns a `np.array`. If you need to convert it back to a list, you lose the speed. Better to just use the array...

```
def m4(n=100000000):
    return np.arange(n).tolist()

>>> timeit.timeit(m4,number=1)
11.485261309993803
```

Comment: For completeness, do `list(np.arange(n))`

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `np.arange(n).tolist()` would be more appropriate - it's faster, and produces ordinary Python ints rather than NumPy ints.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, then you lose the speed advantage... see edits

Comment: @sacul: If the values are known to fall within `range(-2**31, 2**31)` or `range(2**32)`, you can speed up `np.arange` (and halve the memory usage) by explicitly providing a `dtype` of `np.int32` or `np.uint32` respectively. `np.arange` kinda infers the type from the arguments, but the heuristic is "if arguments are integers, and fit in a C `int64_t`, the `dtype` is `int64`, otherwise it's `float64` for huge positive values, and `object` for huge negative values". When you know better, `dtype=np.int32` halves memory and almost halves runtime to boot (for me, ~150 ms dropped to ~82 ms).